# html elements created by javascript not showing on page

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

I'm quite new to javascript. I am trying to create html elements through javascript for a class project but nothing is showing on my page. I may be missing something basic and I would appreciate all help and will take note

html

```
<div id="shirts"></div>
```

javascript

```
function shirt(name, stock, price, image) {
  this.name = name;
  this.stock = stock;
  this.price = price;
  this.image = image;
}


var shirtArray = [];

var whiteShirt = new shirt ("White Shirt", 19, 20.00, "img/whiteT.jpg")
var orangeShirt = new shirt ("Orange Shirt", 4, 20.00, "img/orangeT.jpg")
var yellowShirt = new shirt ("Yellow Shirt", 3, 20.00, "img/yellowT.jpg")
var blackShirt = new shirt ("Black Shirt", 6, 20.00, "img/blackT.jpg")
var greenShirt = new shirt ("Green Shirt", 12, 20.00, "img/greenT.jpg")
var purpleShirt = new shirt ("Purple Shirt", 0, 20.00, "img/purpleT.jpg")

// push objects into array

shirtArray.push(whiteShirt, orangeShirt, yellowShirt, blackShirt, greenShirt, purpleShirt)

for(var i = 0; i < shirtArray.length; i++) {
  var textName = document.createTextNode (shirtArray[i].name)
  var textStock = document.createTextNode ("Avilable " + shirtArray[i].stock)
  var textPrice = document.createTextNode (shirtArray[i].price)
  var addtCart = document.createTextNode("Add to cart")
  var shirtImg = shirtArray[i].image

  var addItem = document.createElement('div')
  var  newDiv = document.createElement('div')
  var  nameH1 = document.createElement('h1')
  var  stockH3 = document.createElement('h3')
  var  priceH4 = document.createElement('h4')
  var  addCart = document.createElement('button')
  var  image = document.createElement('img')

    nameH1.appendChild(textName)
    stockH3.appendChild(textStock)
    priceH4.appendChild(textPrice)
    addCart.appendChild(addtCart)
    addCart.ClassName = "btn btn-warning"
    img.src = shirtImg
    image.ClassName = "img-responsive"

    addItem.ClassName = "col-sm-4"
    newDiv.ClassName = "shirts shirtBrand" + i + " thumbnail "
    newDiv.appendChild(nameH1)
    newDiv.appendChild(stockH3)
    newDiv.appendChild(priceH4)
    newDiv.appendChild(addCart)
    addItem.appendChild(newDiv)

    document.getElementById("shirts").appendChild(addItem)
}
```

Comment: there was a spelling mistake in for loop and there is an undefined variable `img`. write `image` instead of `img`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct splleing in   `shirtArray.length` and also `img` is undefined.You have created variable  `image` and using `img` instead of that.Change variable `img`  to `image` and append `image` to your `div`

```js
function shirt(name, stock, price, image) {
  this.name = name;
  this.stock = stock;
  this.price = price;
  this.image = image;
}


var shirtArray = [];

var whiteShirt = new shirt ("White Shirt", 19, 20.00, "img/whiteT.jpg")
var orangeShirt = new shirt ("Orange Shirt", 4, 20.00, "img/orangeT.jpg")
var yellowShirt = new shirt ("Yellow Shirt", 3, 20.00, "img/yellowT.jpg")
var blackShirt = new shirt ("Black Shirt", 6, 20.00, "img/blackT.jpg")
var greenShirt = new shirt ("Green Shirt", 12, 20.00, "img/greenT.jpg")
var purpleShirt = new shirt ("Purple Shirt", 0, 20.00, "img/purpleT.jpg")

/* push objects into array*/
 
shirtArray.push(whiteShirt, orangeShirt, yellowShirt, blackShirt, greenShirt, purpleShirt)

for(var i = 0; i < shirtArray.length; i++) {
  var textName = document.createTextNode (shirtArray[i].name)
  var textStock = document.createTextNode ("Avilable " + shirtArray[i].stock)
  var textPrice = document.createTextNode (shirtArray[i].price)
  var addtCart = document.createTextNode("Add to cart")
  var shirtImg = shirtArray[i].image

  var addItem = document.createElement('div')
  var  newDiv = document.createElement('div')
  var  nameH1 = document.createElement('h1')
  var  stockH3 = document.createElement('h3')
  var  priceH4 = document.createElement('h4')
  var  addCart = document.createElement('button')
  var  image = document.createElement('img')

addItem.className ="grid";
 
    nameH1.appendChild(textName)
    stockH3.appendChild(textStock)
    priceH4.appendChild(textPrice)
    addCart.appendChild(addtCart)
    addCart.ClassName = "btn btn-warning"
    
    image.src = shirtImg
    image.ClassName = "img-responsive"

    addItem.ClassName = "col-sm-4"
    newDiv.ClassName = "shirts shirtBrand" + i + " thumbnail "
    newDiv.appendChild(nameH1)
     addItem.appendChild(image)
    newDiv.appendChild(stockH3)
    newDiv.appendChild(priceH4)
    newDiv.appendChild(addCart)
    addItem.appendChild(newDiv)

    document.getElementById("shirts").appendChild(addItem)
}
```

```css
.grid{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  float:left;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="shirts"></div>
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, in depth and worked for me. Thank you I appreciate it! Is there any way I would be able to have the created divs right next to each other rather than listed below each other?

Comment: Use css add style float : left for the div

Comment: @AndrewAbalos you can add styles in javascript.But it would be better if use css.Updated snippet with div floating left

Comment: thank you for going the extra mile, I will keep that in mind! I also found that a few of the classNames had a C capitalized and fixed that as well. I keep going over things like that, rookie mistakes !

Answer (score 0):

for(var i = 0; i < shirgtArray.length; i++)

spelling mistake on shirtArray.length

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! I fixed the spelling mistake and still nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
Below is the correct working code

<div id="shirts"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

function shirt(name, stock, price, image) {
  this.name = name;
  this.stock = stock;
  this.price = price;
  this.image = image;
}


var shirtArray = [];

var whiteShirt = new shirt ("White Shirt", 19, 20.00, "img/whiteT.jpg")
var orangeShirt = new shirt ("Orange Shirt", 4, 20.00, "img/orangeT.jpg")
var yellowShirt = new shirt ("Yellow Shirt", 3, 20.00, "img/yellowT.jpg")
var blackShirt = new shirt ("Black Shirt", 6, 20.00, "img/blackT.jpg")
var greenShirt = new shirt ("Green Shirt", 12, 20.00, "img/greenT.jpg")
var purpleShirt = new shirt ("Purple Shirt", 0, 20.00, "img/purpleT.jpg")

// push objects into array

shirtArray.push(whiteShirt, orangeShirt, yellowShirt, blackShirt, greenShirt, purpleShirt);

for(var i = 0; i < shirtArray.length; i++) {
  var textName = document.createTextNode (shirtArray[i].name)
  var textStock = document.createTextNode ("Avilable " + shirtArray[i].stock)
  var textPrice = document.createTextNode (shirtArray[i].price)
  var addtCart = document.createTextNode("Add to cart")
  var shirtImg = shirtArray[i].image

  var addItem = document.createElement('div')
  var  newDiv = document.createElement('div')
  var  nameH1 = document.createElement('h1')
  var  stockH3 = document.createElement('h3')
  var  priceH4 = document.createElement('h4')
  var  addCart = document.createElement('button')
  var  image = document.createElement('img')

    nameH1.appendChild(textName)
    stockH3.appendChild(textStock)
    priceH4.appendChild(textPrice)
    addCart.appendChild(addtCart)
    addCart.ClassName = "btn btn-warning"
    image.src = shirtImg
    image.ClassName = "img-responsive"

    addItem.ClassName = "col-sm-4"
    newDiv.ClassName = "shirts shirtBrand" + i + " thumbnail "
    newDiv.appendChild(nameH1)
    newDiv.appendChild(stockH3)
    newDiv.appendChild(priceH4)
    newDiv.appendChild(addCart)
    addItem.appendChild(newDiv)

    document.getElementById("shirts").appendChild(addItem)
}

</script>
```